# How can I avoid using globals?

Tags: c

I have this program that I try to run:

```
void get_set(int size, int arr[])
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter number of values to the array : \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Value at %dth place is : \n", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void print_set(int size, int arr[])
{
    int i, flag = 0;
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("\nOriginal array is : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("%d,", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nArray after deleting duplicates : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("%d,", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    flag + 1;
}

void RemoveDuplicates(int size, int arr[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) 
            {
                size--;
                for (k = i; k < size; k++) 
                {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int arr[64] = {0};
    get_set(size, arr);
    print_set(size, arr);
    RemoveDuplicates(size, arr);
    print_set(size, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

In short, the program gets an array with values that I entered, and passes it thru other functions.
I can't get it to pass the array and size to other functions.  I am trying to avoid globals; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the printing function, the flag will always be zero because that's what the code initializes it to.  In this case, you should pass the label string to the function — add `const char *tag` to the argument list, and provide the appropriate tag when you call the function.

Comment: Unrelated: Use a consistent naming scheme. And use self-explanatory names.

Comment: Well, it seems you succeeded on it... there are no globals in your code.  Avoid static and outside of any function variable definitions... you'll get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int get_set(int size, int arr[])
{
    int i;
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of values to the array: ");
    fflush(stdout);      // Usually not strictly necessary, but ensures the prompt appears
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number entered\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (n > size)
        n = size;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Value %d is: ", i + 1);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

static void print_set(const char *tag, int size, int arr[])
{
    int i;
    printf("\n%s: ", tag);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static int RemoveDuplicates(int size, int arr[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) 
            {
                size--;
                for (k = i; k < size; k++) 
                {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    return size;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[64] = {0};
    int size = get_set(64, arr);  // 64 is the maximum; size contains the actual
    print_set("Original array", size, arr);
    size = RemoveDuplicates(size, arr);
    print_set("Duplicates removed", size, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

None of the functions except `main()` are called from outside this file; the functions can all be static, therefore.

Example run:

```
Enter number of values to the array: 12

Value 1 is: 1
Value 2 is: 1
Value 3 is: 1
Value 4 is: 2
Value 5 is: 2
Value 6 is: 3
Value 7 is: 4
Value 8 is: 5
Value 9 is: 99
Value 10 is: 999
Value 11 is: 1
Value 12 is: 1

Original array: 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,99,999,1,1,

Duplicates removed: 1,2,3,4,5,99,999,
```

An alternative redesign of the `print_set()` function would make the `flag` in the original code into a `static int`.  However, that is a far less flexible solution than passing the tag string argument to the function.  Static variables inside functions are occasionally useful, but they should be regarded with a jaundiced eye and avoided when possible, just as global variables should be avoided when possible.

Comment: I had trouble with the flag that was not crucial, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `size` variable in `main` is passed by value to `get_set`, so it will still be `0` in `main`.  You should have `get_set` return the size and assign the result to the `size` variable (or pass `size` by reference) so that you can pass it to `print_set` and `RemoveDuplicates`.

`get_set` doesn't really need `size` as a parameter, unless you change it's meaning to indicate the capacity of the array and add error checking to make sure that you don't overflow it.

The `arr` variable is passed by reference because it is an array which decays into a pointer, so `get_set` will modify the variable in `main`.

Comment: Now i see that `get_set` doesn't need the size, thanks for lighting it up to me.